# How use colorized unicode codes in PS1 on urxvt?

Tags: unicode, colors, urxvt

I would like to have colorized PS1 (this works for me so far), but also use some special characters, when I am on git repository (and let the colors show, if it is up-to-date, have some uncommited changes, is behind master etc etc) and here it fails. (I can set colors for ASCII, I can get the git status and set text to describe it, I cannot show it in color unicodes)

I cannot colorize unicode characters - they went into free boxes - out of colorisation they show as expected:

[image: problem with colorised unicode characters]

Here is example, where I set PS1 to `<<x>>` then set it to character for git, and it works, then set color, it not works good, then set the unicode out of colorised section and it works again.

The terminal is executed under fluxbox with this command:

```
/bin/bash -c LC_CTYPE=cs_CZ.UTF8 urxvt  -tr -sh 35  -tn rxvt-unicode-256color -bg black -fg white -sl 1000  -fn 'xft:Inconsolata for Powerline:style=Medium' -fb 'xft:Inconsolata for Powerline:style=BoldForPowerline'
```

Is there a way to have the git character in yellow? (red, green, ...)?

Comment: `U+E0A0` is a character from _Private Use_ range; Try another font (e.g. 'Cascadia Code PL', 'FuraCode NF', 'Source Code Pro', 'SpaceMono NF', 'Unifont CSUR').

Comment: But it would be in the same Private Use range,  right?